# How would I take a line from a text file and type it into a website using batch?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I want to write a batch file, which would take content from a text file, and type it into a website.

I know you can type into a website using Sendkeys but SendKeys will one work with single letters at a time.

How would I get a batch file to type, say Line1, of the text file into one area, then Line2, into a different area?

Say the text file contents were

```
Google.com
How to tie a shoe
```

So the idea would be to go to `Google.com`, then type `How to tie a shoe`.

Im trying to use something like this, to make listing items for sale easier, as I already have a huge list, with prices, and its taking a lot of time trying to post them.

I know this wont work but this is something ive tried before(This is somewhat edited to what I want)

```
 @ECHO OFF

 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\Desktop"
 SET "destdir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\Desktop"
 SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\PostToBeListed.txt"

 rem make sure arrays are empty
 For %%b IN (name price) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b[ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

 rem Initialise counter and entry array
 SET /a count=0
 SET "price[0]=dummy"

 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
  IF DEFINED price[!count!] (SET /a count+=1&SET "name[!count!]=%%a") ELSE (SET "price[!count!]=%%a")
  )
  rem clear out dummy entry
  SET "price[0]=dummy"
  FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,%count%) DO (
  rem report to console
  ECHO Name: !name[%%c]! Price: !price[%%c]!

 @if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
 rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
 set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

 Start chrome www.website.com
 timeout /t 10
 rem the tabs will place the curser at the right area where info needs entered
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 rem this will insert the info from line one of my file(This will not work as what I am trying to input is a sentence and not a letter)
 %SendKeys% "{%!name[%%c]!%}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 rem this will insert the info from line two of my file
 %SendKeys% "{!price[%%c]!}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 %SendKeys% "{TAB}"
 rem then presses enter to post my listing
 %SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

 goto :EOF
 @end
 // JScript section

 var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
 WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: What did you try so far?  Please provide us with - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  SO is place where we help other programmers, but you did not provide us with code.

Comment: Ive tried Sendkeys but sendkeys will only work if its single letters. Is there anyway at all to type a full sentence into somewhere using batch? Ive tried looking it up and couldn't seem to find anything

Comment: Show us the actual code.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Pretty positive you did not read the help syntax for using `SENDKEYS`.   The curly braces are used for sending special characters.  You don't use the curly braces for sending plain text alphanumeric characters.

Comment: This is how it said to do it when I looked it up for sendkeys. The Repetitive tabs I did do not knowing I could make it more simple

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, it doesn't make sense to define `%sendkeys%` in each run in the loop. Just once is enough.

Second, `%sendkeys%` is able to write a string (i.e. more than one character), which makes your code shorter and so more readable.
Strings can be sent directly (the {syntax} is only necessary to send special keystrokes)

Third, you had some `%` too much with the price string.

Fourth, you forgot the closing `)` to close the `for /L` loop.

Fifth, you didn't construct the hybrid properly.

With all that corrected, it should look like:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\Desktop"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\Desktop"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\PostToBeListed.txt"

rem make sure arrays are empty
For %%b IN (name price) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b[ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
rem Initialise counter and entry array
SET /a count=0
SET "price[0]=dummy"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
echo ----%%a
 IF DEFINED price[!count!] (SET /a count+=1&SET "name[!count!]=%%a") ELSE (SET "price[!count!]=%%a")
)

rem clear out dummy entry
SET "price[0]=dummy"

FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,%count%) DO (
  rem report to console
  ECHO Name: !name[%%c]! Price: !price[%%c]!
  Start chrome www.website.com
  timeout /t 10
  rem the tabs will place the curser at the right area where info needs entered
  %SendKeys% "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
  rem this will insert the info from odd lines of my file
  %SendKeys% "!name[%%c]!"
  %SendKeys% "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
  rem this will insert the info from even lines of my file
  %SendKeys% "!price[%%c]!"
  %SendKeys% "{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}"
) 
goto :EOF
@end
// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Note: You open a new tab for each item. You should think about closing the new browser (tabs) or re-using the current tab (depends on how exactly the used site works).

Comment: For some reason its saying cant find "PostToBeListed.txt" when I have the file. I even copied and pasted to be sure I didn't mess up the name on either file

Comment: does `dir "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\Desktop\PostToBeListed.txt" see it?

Comment: Fixed it. Good deal Man thank you so much